# how to stop tinymce from removing my <link> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, tinymce

Ive ran into a problem with tinymce.

```
dd<script id="kot-id" src="***link here***"></script><div id="kotcalculator"></div><link rel="stylesheet" href="***link here***" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

For some reason it is removing the < link >,
Does anyone know how I would be able to fix this?

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    theme: 'modern',
    skin: 'bstyle',
    branding: false,
    extended_valid_elements:'script[id|language|type|src],link[rel|href|type|media]',
```

Thanks in advance,

~I Quest

Comment: The <link> tag is only valid in the <head> of an HTML document so if you try to put it into the <body> TinyMCE will remove it as its invalid HTML.  

source: https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000Ifp9AAC

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: use fullpage plugin as stated in the above mentioned thread.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
valid_children : "+body[style],+body[link],+*[*]",
valid_elements : '*[*]',
```

This work 100% i lost long time for find solution)

Comment: It's always best to explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using below. For me it works in tinymce 4. It adds html comments inside style tag but even with them it works.

```
<style> @import url....
```

and style should be in valid elements section on tinymce init:

```
valid_elements : "@[id|class|style|....
```